# How to hide owner commands in a embedded help command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm having this issue where I want to hide the commands that should be **owner accessible only**.

This is what the help menu displays:

[image: The small section that shows the owner commands]

And this is the code that is used to make the help menu:

[image: And this the code for the help command]

And I have tried making the commands hidden by doing `@commands.command(hidden=True)` However it does not hide them.

And I looked through the Discord.py documentation and can't seem to find anything to help with my query.

Comment: iirc, the `hidden=True` only applies to the default help message. If you want to hide certain commands from your custom help command, I'd recommend checking the command name against a list of hidden commands if you don't want them being displayed.

Comment: @Diggy. I actually made a solution to this issue this morning. I did cogs.remove('Owner'). This lets me remove the owner cog from the cog list, which doesn't remove the cog's functionality but rather the name and it commands from the help menu.

Answer (score 0):

I added `cogs.remove('Owner')` which removed the cog and its commands. It only removes its presence from the help menu and not the actual cog itself. I did this on line 29 of the code.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61956746/2) to the question [How to hide owner commands in a embedded help command [discord.py rewrite]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956746/how-to-hide-owner-commands-in-a-embedded-help-command-discord-py-rewrite) by the OP [NeonNingen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12476276/neonningen) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add this `@commands.command(hidden=True)`

When listing the commands, make a query like this

```
if not command.hidden:
   print(command.name)
```

If the command is hidden, it will ignore it when listing commands